# Where have I gone wrong in my work using the Trapezoidal Rule?

Tags: calculus

Basically, I am trying to solve this table [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwG0R.png) using the Trapezoidal Rule. The format I have been taught to use to solve problems like this goes like this: [Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyCOG.png). However, once I solve this problem by using this format, I get an entirely different answer to the correct answer. Once I substitute the values like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWTWb.png), I get the answer of 145.8. However, the actual correct answer is 253.2. I get this answer using other ways, but not this way which I have been taught. Why is that? Any help is appreciated. (Sorry for the excess of images.)

Comment: There should be brackets around everything in your general expression after the $ \ h \ $ ...  It's one-half times the base of each trapezoid times the *sum* of the two end heights **and** twice each of the other heights.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you draw the trapezoids and compute the areas of each using "one-half the height times the sum of the bases."  The height of each trapezoid is 4.  The bases of each trapezoid are the vertical heights.  If you do this, you will get the correct answer of 253.2.